# User-dependent bean definition in Spring

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I'm creating a Spring-based Webapplication where I use Spring to add the implementation of a service to the defined interface. So far, so standard. Works fine.

I want to allow a user to overwrite applications behavior at runtime for his session. For that I want spring to change the implementation behind an interface depending on the user-session.

A use case for that are automatic testcases that run on INT and should test the output of an email created by the system. On INT there is an email-serivce configured sending emails to our mail-server. I dont want the testcase to have to check mails using a mail-Protocol. I want in case automatic testcases are running to chenge the email-implementation to write the email as comments to the HTML, so my tests can easily check the result. And so there are some more such cases where it would be nice to change the implementing bean for special circumstances.

Is there a concept in spring that helps me to implement such a feature or do I have to create that on my own?

Additional information: It's all about automated acceptance tests. That tests run on systems that we share with maunual testers.
=> Manual testers want to get a real email for their tests
=> Automatic tests reduce complexity by not receiving emails, just checking the email-content with less dependencies.
There was no problem, if we had two systems, one configured for humans needs and one for automated tests needs. But thats not the case, so I need a way to change the systems behavior on runtime.

Comment: Sounds like [Spring profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) would be a good choice - one for production and one for testing.

Comment: Sounds a bit strange to me. If you create automatic tests you usually want to either test a module, test some modules together, or test the application. If you change one module by another you will test your application with that test module but not how it behaves in real life - you may want to create some integration or unit tests to verify the behavior of the other modules.

Comment: I want to test the application, for that I need to test the content of the sent email. But I dont want to test the implementation of the mailing-library, our mail-server and the implementation of some kind of mail-client. Of cause it would be more real, but it's making things more complicated and I think it brings more problems than good.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually done in the following way:

1. set up tests using spring-test module which lets you create a spring context for testing and inject beans into your test classes,
2. use the same context files for tests as you do for production except create a separate spring profile where default mail service implementation is substituted with a mock,
3. write a test case where you simulate steps done by user programatically and finally you assert something like `assertEquals("<expected_email_text>", mailServiceMock.getLastEmail())`.

From your question it is not clear why you would deviate from the standard approach described above. If you explained your reasons perhaps it would be easier to come up with an appropriate answer.